# How to check expiry of kubernetes tokens and cert keys?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubeadm

When I create a kubernetes cluster I'm getting message as

As a safeguard, uploaded-certs will be deleted in two hours; If necessary, you can use
`kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs` to reload certs afterward.

Even if I run the above command when will the new certs expire? Is there any way to set expiration time manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expiry of certificates generated by kubeadm is 365 days. For safety reasons the certificates which are uploaded as secrets into the kubernetes cluster are deleted after 2 hours but that does not mean that the certificates are expired after 2 hours. Certificates will still be valid for 365 days and reside in the file system of the control plane nodes and when you run `kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs` it will be uploaded again as secret into the Kubernetes cluster.

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/) you can use below command to check expiration of certificates

```
kubeadm certs check-expiration
```

Comment: does the secrets keep expiring after every 2hrs, even after executing "kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs" ?

Comment: Yes it will expire after 2 hours. It's documented here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#uploading-control-plane-certificates-to-the-cluster